# Booking events do not trigger an action and missing in module

Tags: rules, bookings

Am using the [Booking Time Slot](https://www.drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots) module in my project.

I configured some booking related [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and noticed that they were not triggered.

While trying to debug the rules configuration, I noticed that no information was logged in the System logs.

Also while going through the [Booking Time Slot](https://www.drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots) module, i could not find the Rules event in the module files.

My question is that in what files can the booking rules event be and how can i get the rules configuration to work.
[image: Screen Shot of the Booking event]